# Kubernetes Dashboard: Service Accounts

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to view Service Accounts via the Kubernetes Dashboard?

I can see a token that was created for the Service Account under Secrets but struggling to actually find the Service Account listed anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to list all Service Acccounts under specific submenu in Kubernetes Dashboard but you can view owner `Service Account` of Secrets by clicking on them under `Details/Annotations:` section as `kubernetes.io/service-account.name:  <service-account-name>`

For additional information, you can visit below links:
[Web UI (Dashboard)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#using-dashboard).

And also for github project https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/

Hope it will be useful for you